SVG SMIL start animation at current state for arbitrary attribute
I want to create an transition from the current state to a new state for an arbitrary attribute. I have this code:
const animate: SVGAnimateElement; 

function transition(attribute: keyof SVGGElement, to: string) {
    const initialState = animate.parentElement[attribute].animVal;
    animate.setAttribute('from', initialState);
    animate.setAttribute('to', to);
    animate.beginElement();
}

This works fine for string or numeric attributes, but sometimes the attribute will be an SVGRect or an SVGTransformList or any other non-string type. setAttribute only accepts strings.
Is there a good way to either:

Convert an arbitrary attribute value from animState to a string suitable for use in setAttribute.
Directly set the value in animate to a more complex object like SVGRect or SVGTransformList
Start the animation from the current state in some other way.

I can't use CSS transititions since it doesn't support some attributes (like viewBox)

@RobertLongson That just returns "[object SVGRect]" which I can't set with setAttribute

Can you add a runnable example with Stack Snippets

You need the value property on the animVal object to get the current value. An then you also need to change the attributeName attribute.


const animate = document.querySelector('animate');

transition('cy', 80);

function transition(attribute, to) {
  const initialState = animate.parentElement[attribute].animVal.value;
  animate.setAttribute('attributeName', attribute);
  animate.setAttribute('from', initialState);
  animate.setAttribute('to', to);
  animate.beginElement();
}
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100">
  <circle cx="20" cy="10" r="15" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <animate
      attributeName="cx"
      from="0"
      to="100"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
  </circle>
</svg>




This does not seem to work for more complex attributes like viewBox

the animVal of the viewBox is an object that looks like this: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100 } -- so, it does not have a value. OK, so I guess it dependent on the individual attribute how the value should be handled.


Is there a good way to either:

Convert an arbitrary attribute value from animState to a string suitable for use in setAttribute.


You will have to write case distinctions yourself, and even a serialization method at least in some cases like SVGRect. SVGTransformList can be serialized via SVGTransformList.consolidate().matrix.toString().


Directly set the value in animate to a more complex object like SVGRect or SVGTransformList


No. The spec states:

Unlike other SVG DOM interfaces, the SVG DOM does not specify convenience DOM properties corresponding to the various language attributes on SVG's animation elements...The current method for accessing and modifying the attributes on the animation elements is to use the standard getAttribute, setAttribute,...



Start the animation from the current state in some other way.


Manipulating the animation timeline would be the domain of WAAPI, as it was initially intended. But in fact it is only implemented for CSS animations and transitions. Nobody works on implementing it for SMIL, or even on writing an appropriate spec.
